# What's an efficient way to pluck an element out of a list and return the element, and rest of list in a tuple?

Tags: haskell

This seems to be a very common operation but I can't find it in hoogle for some reason. Either way, it's an interesting thought exercise. My naive implementation:

```
pluckL :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe ( a, [a] )
pluckL xs idx = if idx < length xs then Just $ pluck' xs idx else Nothing
where
    pluck' l n = let subl = drop n l in ( head subl, rest l n ++ tail subl )
    rest   l n = reverse $ drop ( length l - n ) $ reverse l
```

My main gripe is that I'm flipping the list too many times, so I'm looking for a creative way where you can traverse the list once and generate the tuple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There will never be an efficient way. But there can at least be a pretty way:

```
pluckL xs i = case splitAt i xs of
    (b, v:e) -> Just (v, b ++ e)
    _ -> Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get by with one fewer `reverse` and fewer operations on the list if you use an accumulator:

```
pluckL :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe (a, [a])
pluckL xs idx = pluck xs idx [] where
    pluck (x:xs) 0 acc = Just $ ( x, (reverse acc) ++ xs )
    pluck (x:xs) i acc = pluck xs (i-1) (x:acc)
    pluck [] i acc = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **elem** to check if the elem is in the list or not, then depending of the result  return Nothing or use **delete x** to remove x from the list, as follow for example,

```
pluckL :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Maybe (a, [a]) 
pluckL xs0 x =  
    if (x `elem` xs0) 
    then Just (x, xs) 
    else Nothing
        where xs = delete x xs0
```